# How to expect attribute value with timeout using Playwright

Tags: python, playwright

This is my code:

```py
expect(self.page.wait_for_selector(CSS_OF_ELEMENT, timeout=5000))\
    .to_have_attribute('aria-disabled', value)
```

My goal is to wait for an element with a given timeout, and search for the value of the attribute 'aria-disabled'.

The code doesn't compile. I get this error:

```
{ValueError}Unsupported type: <class 'playwright.sync_api._generated.ElementHandle'>
```

How do I fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```py
expect("SELECTOR").to_have_attribute("aria-disabled", "value", timeout=5000)
```